# Mail Chimp API and Different Arrays

Tags: php, mailchimp

Ok. I'm using a script from Aaron Walter to connect to MailChimps API.

There are three spots on the website and I'd like to "track" where the signup came from. I'm able to get this to work with the following code but can't wrap my mind around how to adjust this code so that there are 3 different possibilities.

```
function storeAddress(){

// Validation
if(!$_GET['email']){ return "No email address provided"; } 

if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i", $_GET['email'])) {
    return "Email address is invalid"; 
}

require_once('MCAPI.class.php');
// grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
$api = new MCAPI('myAPIkey');

// grab your List's Unique Id by going to http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/
// Click the "settings" link for the list - the Unique Id is at the bottom of that page. 
$list_id = "myLISTid";

//this line will allow me to see "headerBox" under sign up method within
// mailchimp so I know what form was used to sign up
$merge_vars = array('signup' =>'headerBox'); 

if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], $merge_vars) === true) {
    // It worked!   
    return 'Success! Check your email (and spam folder!) for your guide.';
}
else
{
    // An error ocurred, return error message   
    return 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
}




}
```

The problem I'm facing involves this line:

```
 $merge_vars = array('signup' =>'headerBox');
```

`"signup"` will have three different values, depending on which spot they accessed the form from. I hope I've been clear enough.

EDIT:
From the code above, why wouldn't something like this work?
Put a hidden input field for each of the forms and check to see what value is given...

```
if($_GET['signupMethod']=='headerBox') {
    $merge_vars = array('signup' =>'headerBox');
}
if($_GET['signupMethod']=='popUp') {
    $merge_vars = array('signup' =>'popUp');
}
if($_GET['signupMethod']=='footer') {
    $merge_vars = array('signup' =>'footer');
}

//continue with code
if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], $merge_vars) === true) {
    // It worked!   
    return 'Success! Check your email (and spam folder!) for your guide.';
}
else
{
    // An error ocurred, return error message   
    return 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
}
```

Comment: This was what mailchimp support suggested I do. I need that value to be different depending on what form is used. I thought about perhaps putting a hidden text field and assigning a value to it, then checking the value with a couple if statements but couldn't get it to work. Does that make sense?

Comment: I added some code above in an edit.

Comment: No. The method is definitely get. It is working. I just can't figure out how to change the value of 'signup' depending on the form submitted.

Comment: @A-2-A I just did. I don't think I was able to at the time or something. Thanks for the reminder. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As you stated that your form method is `GET` and you created a hidden field with name `signupMethod`, do like below:-**

```
<?php
function storeAddress(){

// Validation
if(!$_GET['email']){ return "No email address provided"; } 

if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i", $_GET['email'])) {
    return "Email address is invalid"; 
}

require_once('MCAPI.class.php');
// grab an API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
$api = new MCAPI('myAPIkey');

// grab your List's Unique Id by going to http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/
// Click the "settings" link for the list - the Unique Id is at the bottom of that page. 
$list_id = "myLISTid";

$merge_vars = ''; //define variable first and then assign values in next lines by checking it's value

if(isset($_GET['signupMethod']) && $_GET['signupMethod']=='headerBox') {
    $merge_vars = array('signup' =>'headerBox');
}
if(isset($_GET['signupMethod']) && $_GET['signupMethod']=='popUp') {
    $merge_vars = array('signup' =>'popUp');
}
if(isset($_GET['signupMethod']) && $_GET['signupMethod']=='footer') {
    $merge_vars = array('signup' =>'footer');
}


if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_GET['email'], $merge_vars) === true) {
    // It worked!   
    return 'Success! Check your email (and spam folder!) for your guide.';
}
else
{
    // An error ocurred, return error message   
    return 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
}
?>
```

Comment: It won't print. Undefined index again.

Comment: I've searched and can't find any documentation or answers to my problem.

Comment: no. the store-address piece is in an includes directory.

Comment: No go brother. Same thing. It's storing my email within the list but no signup variable is present. This is absolutely blowing my mind!